# Bluescreen Stop 0x00000027 RDR_FILE_SYSTEM after cloning system on new HDD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, bsod

A couple of months ago I got a new 500GB HDD for my no-name-brand Laptop PC and I cloned the complete Win 7 Pro 32bit system with clonezilla from the old 70GB drive to the new one. At first everything was great, the new driver was immediately updated.

But since then I get on a more and more frequent level (used to be every 2-3 days, but now it's more like 2-3 times a day) a BSOD Stop error. From the eventlog in Windows I know that there are two different error codes sppoking aroung:

```
0x00000027 (0xbaad0073, 0x9954f80c, 0x9954f3f0, 0x8ecd7c82) RDR_FILE_SYSTEM

0x00000044 (0x85443230, 0x00000eae, 0x00000000, 0x00000000) MULTIPLE_IRP_COMPLETE_REQUESTS
```

I checked for viruses and did a complete HDD check using the Windows tool and WesternDigital tool (which is the producer of the new HDD) without results. I also looked for driver updates but couldn't find any.

The name of the HDD as shown in the device manager is:

> WDC WD5000BPVT-00HXZT1 ATA Device.

I'm really a noob regarding those kind of problems, so if you have any idea what I can try without losing all my data, let me know. Also, if any additional information are required.

Comment: Have you run a CHKDSK lately?

Comment: Some potential clues (MULTIPLE_IRP: vista usb goes idle): http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973056, (RDR : windows 7 offline encrypted files) http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981109. NOTE THAT STOP errors usually reference a module. This module is important.

Comment: CHKDSK doesn't show any errors. Where do I find the module reference?

Comment: did you sysprep this system before you tried to clone it?

Answer (score 0):

Might be a problem with the "NEW" hard drive, I would run a quick [S.M.A.R.T.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) check on it.

On Linux there is a utility called [Parted Magic](http://partedmagic.com/).

While S.M.A.R.T. attributes are not definitive, i.e. a drive can pass S.M.A.R.T. tests and still be bad, it can usually point you in the right direction.

A failing drive will turn the program's tab red, look for reallocated sectors and ATA errors.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue when imaging machines with different hard drive sizes using Clonezilla. The tool I use to diagnose this issue is called "BlueScreenView". This is a pretty handle tool when it comes to troubleshooting the infamous Blue Screen. It gives you indepth information about the error codes. It would be put to better use if trying to troubleshoot the issues you are having, and then potentially lead you to a solution specific to your issues.

You can download it here:
http://majorgeeks.com/BlueScreenView_d6200.html